# Vinyl floor against odd shape threshold

Tags: vinyl-flooring

[image][image]

Hello, I'm trying to figure it what to do with this threshold on my 3 season porch. I'm planning on pulling up the carpet and laying vinyl plank. This is the threshold into the house. It's about an inch tall land comes out into the room about an inch. I'm thinking maybe I could miter some L molding to make a U shape around the threshold.

Any one dealt with something similar?

Comment: Do you intend to pull out the white painted base molding (to the right of the threshold in the picture) and install new molding along the walls?

Comment: Yeah. Either I'll notch the vinyl around the threshold and install quarter round on top, or replace that molding with something that fills the space and overlaps the vinyl.

Comment: I think, in front of the threshold you could just do the paint-grade quarter-round and miter a short return to whatever ends up at the wall. If you paint it to match the threshold it will be difficult to even see that it's there, but it will cover and hold down the vinyl edge...

Comment: That would be a lot simpler than what I was imagining... I'm worried that the top of the quarter round and the edge of the threshold (which is quite worn) will look weird together.

Comment: Use 1/2" quarter round, don't try to match the height. It will just look like a detail at the base of the threshold...

Comment: Hmmm, I pulled up the carpet and things are different than I expected. I'm just going to post a new question rather than significantly edit this one.

Comment: https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/166466/76121